# How to add Kineticjs shape Circle on Kineticjs Text onclick?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I wanna be able to click on var textradie text "Show radie" and then add two circles kinGroups[index].add(circle); and kinGroups[index].add(circlered);. Im adding the two circles on my Group kinGroups[index].
All my jsonObjects[i].radie == false, so I dont know why only one object in kinGroups[index] have two circles. All my three objects should have two circles, but only one object have two circles.

```
var textradius = new Kinetic.Text({

    x: 1000,
    y: 500,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: 18,
    text: 'Show radius',
    fill: 'black'
});

kinGroups[index].add(textradie);

textradius.on('click', function() {

    for(i=0; i<jsonObjects.length; i++) {

        console.log("testing");

        if(kinGroups[index].getName() == jsonObjects[i].name) {

            if(jsonObjects[i].radie == false) {

                    kinGroups[index].add(circle);
                    kinGroups[index].add(circlered);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **new** circle and circlered objects to the groups.

You could use the clone() method to do this:

```
kinGroups[index].add(circle.clone());
kinGroups[index].add(circlered.clone());
```

**[ Addition: example code ]**

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4uAdc/

Assume you have:

- A group,
- A text element in that group. The text element is named "One".
- Other elements in that group. Some of the other elements are named "One".

If you click on the text named "One", here's how to draw a double-circle around the other elements that are also named "One".

```
// define a circle that can be cloned
var circle=new Kinetic.Circle({
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
});

// get all children with the same name as the clicked text

var children=group.find("."+text.getName());

// iterate those children and add cloned circles

for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){


    // get the x,y of the other elements with the same name as the text

    var child=children[i];
    var x=child.getX();
    var y=child.getY();

    // add cloned circles around those other elements

    var red =circle.clone({x:x,y:y,radius:10,stroke:"red"});
    var blue=circle.clone({x:x,y:y,radius:15,stroke:"blue"});
    text.group.add(red);
    text.group.add(blue);

}
layer.draw();
```

Comment: @markeE Hi! Thanks, but your code did not solve the problem, It is still displaying the circle and circled only around one object , and not the three objects.

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what you need with the little code you've given, but I've added an example to my answer that gets all of a group's children with the same name as clicked-text and draws double circles around those selected children.  Cheers!